# How to use Conditional WHERE Clause in MySql under this kind of circumstance?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to data analytics and I have just met a problem while doing a practice, my practice data is as blow:[practice_movie_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITciF.png)

So the practice requires sorting the data via `Release Data` while conditioning the `Genre` as **Comedy** and `Revenue` to be greater than **$300 million**.
The tutorial showed the case on Bigquery will run successfully as like this:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    movie_data
WHERE
    Genre = 'Comedy'
    AND Revenue > 300000000
ORDER BY 
    `Release Date`
    DESC
```

But when I tried it on Mysql, there are no results shown as I can tell the data type for the `Revenue` Column is `Varchar(255)`, so I tried this:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    movie_data
WHERE
    Genre = 'Comedy'
    AND CAST(Revenue AS FLOAT) AND Revenue > 300000000)
ORDER BY 
    `Release Date`
    DESC
```

Unfortunately, I got errors, please help me with this!
I appreciate all the helpful answers.

Comment: Is the release date column named `Release Date` as this shouldn't be the case, likely `release_date` I'd assume

Comment: There is no point in direct `Revenue` converting until it contains excess chars (`$`) - CAST will produce zero. Remove this excess char then use the value (and CAST not needed in this case).

Comment: It is also helpful if you can include the table structure in your question.

Comment: Does you data actually contain the `$` signs?

Comment: Count `(` and `)`. Same number?

Comment: @jarlh also the brackets are not opened, but closed at the end

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes it does, and it also contains `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the unwanted characters then converting / casting it:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    movie_data
WHERE
    Genre = 'Comedy'
    AND CONVERT(REPLACE(REPLACE(Revenue,'$',''),',',''),DECIMAL(12,2)) > 300000000
ORDER BY 
    `Release Date`
    DESC
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now! Could you also explain a bit about why `REPLACE` is used twice? And for this case, can I use `CAST` instead of `CONVERT`?

Comment: You can use cast instead, replace is used twice because it first removes the dollar sign, then removes the `,`  from the number (because MySQL doesn't understand number in such a format), so basically from for example `$1,000,000.15` you are getting `1000000.15`

Comment: Oh I finally get it! And I have just tried CAST and it worked! Thank you so much!